# Swap data attributes sorting with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list that is set up with data attributes on each list item pertaining to the sort order

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li data-id="1" data-sort="1">
        Item
    </li>
    <li data-id="4" data-sort="2">
        Item
    </li>
    <li data-id="12" data-sort="3">
        Item
        <ul class="sortable">
            <li data-id="3" data-sort="4">
                Item
            </li>
            <li data-id="7" data-sort="5">
                Item
            </li>
            <li data-id="15" data-sort="6">
                Item
            </li>
            <li data-id="9" data-sort="7">
                Item
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which you can reorder using jQuery UI Sortable...

However, when the user does change the order, I want the data-sort attributes swap out so they maintain the consistent sort order -- while still maintaining their original data-id.

I tried messing around with the index, but since I have UL within UL, the index resets per list. Whereas, you see in my code, the sort order is consistent throughout the whole main UL.

```
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var start_sort = $(ui.item).data("sort"));
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            // code ??
        },
        receive : function(event, ui) {
            // code ??
        }

    }).disableSelection();
```

Any input would be appreciated. I may not even have the right idea for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `index()` you can just loop for each and use the loops index.

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
    update: function(e,ui) {
        $('.sortable li').each(function(index, value) {
            $(this).attr("data-sort", index+1);
        });
    },
    start: // rest of your code
}).disableSelection();
```

Open up your console and test: https://jsfiddle.net/r62r0b26/